Is there a phone app to direct me at the gym?
Is there an app which can tell me exactly what to do at the gym (from a pre-prepared program), and then I click "next" when I've done it?  For example "Do 10 reps of 40KG on the x machine now."
I'm sure the purists will be deeply offended by this question, but despite having good success with running (I run 10 miles several times a week) I've not yet been able to make the gym stick.  I find it un-directed and frustrating as an experience, doing some work and then waiting for a period of time.  I don't know if an app telling me what to do the whole time would help, but it might do.
Thanks.

It's really not the best fit on the site, but have you tried googling "android gym training app"? There are a few dozen, and most of the top ones have reviews and information. As Shog9 once said "We are not trying to replicate google". Show us what you have looked at and why they aren't working and we can give greater assistance.
